# Resize a Graphics Path on MouseMove

Tags: c#, gdi+

In GDI+ and C#, I have created a Table using Graphics Path using AddRectangle and AddLine Methods

[image]

Now during my Mouse Move, I would like to resize/move this complete Table.

I can iterate over all Sub-Paths and re-calculate everything during mouse move, but I was wondering is there any method by which I can move or resize this complete Graphics Path in one Go.

Comment: I think its possible to resize a bitmap if your drawing to one

Comment: @Sayse, Thanks for your reply but I am not drawing to any Bitmap I am drawing it directly on a Panel in Winforms.

Comment: can you modify your code to draw to a bitmap then in turn put this bitmap on the panel? other wise you will have to iterate

EDIT: or get a bitmap from a region of your panel maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is GraphicsPath.Transform.

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.Scale(scaleX, scaleY, MatrixOrder.Append);
m.Translate(offsetX, offsetY, MatrixOrder.Append);
path.Transform(m);
```

It's probably not good to transform a path too many times, though, given that GDI+ uses only single-precision floats. I'd suggest keeping an original path that you transform as needed.

Or you could edit the transform on a Graphics object before you draw, or rebuild your path before every draw. You'll get the same result however you do it. A transformed path isn't going to draw any faster than a new one, and the time it takes to build the path is probably negligible. So I'd guess that recalculating is simplest to write, and it has no disadvantage that I can think of.